# PHP web socket gets times out after some time

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

So I'm new in web sockets specially in php so i tried this helper library called socketo.me.
Every thing works fine socket connects gets messages, populates messages to all clients but only problem is it gets timed out after sometime that i dont know. One day i leave socket connected and the very next morning I come and try to connect and its not connecting and i have to restart socket (Server keeps running).
Here is the code im using to run socket.

```
public static function actioninitialize(){

    $server = IoServer::factory(
            new Chat(),
            28
    );

    $server->run();

}
```

28 is the port im using and Chat() is the message interface im using to receive and populate messages

```
 class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later

    $this->clients->attach($conn);
    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}

public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {




            foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                    $client->send('eg' );
            }

}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

    $conn->close();
}
}
```

So, iv seen their documentation and all but couldnt find where is this timeout thing coming from. I have seen php documentation aswell and saw some things and tried but nothing helped.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. WebSocket protocol has a keepalive mechanism named [ping-pong](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2). You may want to try to [enable it](http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.WebSocket.Version.RFC6455.Frame.html) in your app. Alternatively you can implement the same thing with messages. The goal is to show the world that your TCP connection is being used.
2. Connections break all the time for a lot of reasons from accidentally closed browser tab to your OS not liking long connections to a NAT server crash at your ISP. Usually an app should be able to detect a failed connection, drop it and create the new one without any impact on user experience (though *reconnecting* message would be nice if we're talking about a chat).

Comment: Will try the ping pong mechanism and see if it works, meanwhile is it an alternative approach to refresh connection every other timestamp. Let's say every 4 hours or so ?

Comment: @sajawalsz yes, this is also possible.